# Method that compares each char of string to "*"and it will also compare if char before"*"and one after are the same it returns true or false

Tags: java, string, char, boolean

this is the code I used to compare the chars in String that is input to "*" and then would also check the chars before and after "*" to see if they are similar in order to return true or false, however the code has an error that says a return value is missing, which i have no clue why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class everyOtherLetter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("type a word");

        String input = y.next();

        char[] t = input.toCharArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));

        //calling the function for even numbers
        //everyOtherLetter(input, true);

        //calling the function for odd numbers
        //everyOtherLetter(input, false);
        sameStarChar(input);

    }

    private static void everyOtherLetter(String input, boolean even) {
        int i =1;

        if(even) { //if we need even chars, start with 1;

            i=0;

        }

        for(; i < input.length(); i = i + 2){

            System.out.println(input.charAt(i));

        }
    }

    private static boolean sameStarChar(String input) {

        int i=0;

        for (;i < input.length();i=i+1){

            if (input.substring(i,(i+1))=="*"){


                if(input.substring((i-1),i)==input.substring((i+1),(i+2))){

                    return true;
                }

                else 

                    return false;
            }  
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (input.substring(i,(i+1))=="*")`, `if(input.substring((i-1),i)==input.substring((i+1),(i+2)))` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Aside: consider `for (int i = even ? 0 : 1; i < input.length(); i += 2) {`   It saves four lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
    for (;i < input.length();i=i+1){
        if (input.substring(i,(i+1))=="*"){
            if(input.substring((i-1),i)==input.substring((i+1),(i+2))){
                return true;
            }
            else 
                return false;
        }  
    }
```

(As pointed out in a comment, `==` is wrong; use `equals()`.)

If your code finds a `*`, then it will check the characters before and after to see if they're equal.  If they are, it will return `true` from the whole method; if not, the method will return `false`.  I think this logic is wrong, but I don't completely understand the requirements.

But the reason for the error is: what happens if there is no `*` in the string?  Or if the `for` loop never executes (because the input string is empty)?  Then the code will complete the `for` loop without ever returning anything.  Then what happens?  The code has to return something.  The compiler sees that if you get to this point, the method will return without a `return` statement telling it what value to return, which is a no-no (except for a `void` method).  That's why you're getting the error.  You may think that the input will never be empty and will always have `*` somewhere in it, but the compiler doesn't know that.  So you'll need a `return` or `throw` somewhere after the loop.

I'm suspicious of your logic.  Is it possible for there to be more than one `*` in the string?  If so, then what is the method supposed to do--check only the first one, or check all of them?  If the method needs to make sure that the characters around every `*` are the same, then the method cannot return `true` until it has checked all of them.  This means that you cannot return `true` until the loop is completed.  You're returning `true` from inside the loop, which will give you the wrong answer.  I'm not certain of this, since I don't really know the specifics of what the method is supposed to accomplish.  But this is a common mistake among newer programmers who use a loop to try to search for something or test all occurrences of something.

(One final note: if you are looking at individual characters, it's much easier to use `charAt()` instead of `substring()`.)